# Parsing only the numbers from given arguments

Tags: c, arguments

How do you parse out only the first 10 numbers from any given number of arguments in C, and then output it as a telephone number? For example, if a file is called `function` and the given command is `function hi1234567890` it would return `(123)456-7890`. Similarily, if the user inputs three arguments `function 123 hi 456` it might return something saying there aren't enough numbers. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char phone[13]; // array to store phone number

   int i;
   int j;
   int len;
   int num;

   for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      len = strlen(argv[i]);
      for(j = 0; j < len; j++) {
         num = atoi(argv[i][j]);
         if ( isdigit(num) != 0 ) {
            phone[j] = argv[i][j];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is definitely not working, there's something wrong with the atoi() which in turn is causing the isdigit() to not work and I'm not storing it in the array correctly.

Comment: It is not making any sense to call `isdigit` on `int`. Also `atoi` will return `0` on failure, which you won't be able to distinguish from the "real" `0`. Use `strtol` instead.

Comment: The internet says: "Function isdigit() takes a single argument in the form of an integer and returns the value of type int."

Comment: Well, I kinda misspoke. `isdigit` is actually taking an `int`, but it is interpreting it as character code. But you give it an output of `atoi` which is a number already.

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't make sense. `isdigit()` can't take in `num` unless I use atoi to make `argv[i][j]` an int first.

Comment: Ok, if it doesn't check the result of following: `isdigit('5')` versus `isdigit(5)`.

Comment: So I just don't need the `atoi()` then since it takes in a `char` apparently

Comment: Correct. If you want your number as string, it should be sufficient.

Comment: Just make sure not to overflow your `phone` array, and terminate it with `'\0'`

Comment: the phone number may is never typed as as bunch of digits without spaces, minuses parenthesizes or dots. For exmaple (555) 340-345-6789

Comment: As the phone number may contain leading zeros, calling `atoi()` or `strtol()`, etc, will loose that information.  To parse 10 _digits_, code character processing.

Comment: `atoi(3)` needs a `char *` (a null terminated string) as parameter, and you are passing it a `char` value.  It is normal that `atoi()` doesn't work.  Check the documentation of `atoi(char *)` function.

Answer (score 0):

As [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) pointed out you have to parse the string character by character. atoi() and strtol() will read all digits (and throw away leading zeros) until a non-digit is met which makes it difficult for you to control the number of characters read.

Try out something along the line

```
int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
    char phone_number [14];
    int  digit_count;       /* counter for digits */
    int  p;                 /* pointer into phone_number */
    int  i, a;              /* loop variables */
    int  arg_len;           /* no. of chars in current arg */

    /* loop over arguments */
    for (a=1; a<argc; a++) 
        {
        arg_len = strlen (argv [a]);
        phone_number [0] = '(';
        p=1;
        digit_count=0;

        /* parse current argument */
        for (i=0; i<arg_len; i++) 
            {
            /* safe digit */
            if (isdigit (argv [a][i]))
                {
                phone_number [p] = argv[a][i];
                p++;
                digit_count++;
                }

            /* insert format */
            if (p == 4)
                {
                phone_number [p] = ')';
                p++;
                }
            if (p == 8)
                {
                phone_number [p] = '-';
                p++;
                }

            /* read ten digits -> finished */
            if (digit_count == 10)
                {
                phone_number [p] = '\0';
                break;
                }
            }

        /* check for enough digits */
        if (digit_count < 10)
            {
            printf ("Argument had only %d digits\n!", digit_count);
            continue;
            }

        printf ("Phone_number (%d): %s\n", a, phone_number);
        }
}
```

This gives:

```
$ ./a.out hi1234567890 abc123456jfhj789649 a75849gfj5
Phone_number (1): (123)456-7890
Phone_number (2): (123)456-7896
Argument 3 had only 6 digits
```